# check system Sleep state in script

Tags: powershell, sleep-mode

Is there a way in Powershell to see if the machine/system is currently in Sleep state/mode or not? I would like to skip some code when the machine is in Sleep state.

Comment: I ran some powershell in a while loop and slept my system, and the loop paused during sleep. So I'm not sure how you're even doing this. But maybe try `Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDevice` ? You can see the power state of each device.

Comment: Yeah, `$IsSleeping = $false`. Kidding aside, when your machine enters a low power state execution of all user mode threads is halted by the OS - the processes are effectively suspended, so "am I running during sleep" is a moot question